# Are there any sans-serif fonts metric-compatible with Computer Modern?

Tags: fonts, computer-modern, font-metrics

The default LaTeX font is Computer Modern, a serif font. There is also a sans-serif alternative. However, it is not **metric compatible**. This means that the sizes each character can differ, and this can change the layout of the document when switching fonts.

My question is, **are there any sans-serif fonts metric-compatible with computer modern?** The reason I want to do this is that I find sans-serif fonts easier to read on my screen, but I want the final export of this document to be serif, and it will be easier if the layout does not change when the font changes.

(I apologize that this is a fonts question in a LaTeX forum, but I figure most people with this particular problem will be using LaTeX. I hope this is appropriate for this StackExchange.)

Comment: I can think of a few kludges to match character widths with an existing sans serif font.  However, they would not allow for hyphenation, not would kernings match.  Thus, your goal of a perfect layout match would not be achieved.